# Internet Explorer console throws error when passing variable with ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, runtime-error

I have a js function

```
function getdata(gender,filtervals,limit) {
//alert("Hi");  
    $(".photo,.info").html('...Loading....');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'data.php',
        data: {
            filtervals : filtervals,
            gender : gender, // This is where the error is mentioned
            limit : limit
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if(result){
                $("#List").html(result);
                $("#List").css('display','block');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I get an error in IE (Only in IE) console saying 'expected ":"' at line 169 which I have identified with by commenting that on the right side

This code works well on chrome and firefox but not on IE and some mobile browsers.

Been trying to narrow down why my entire javascript is not working on IE and some mobile browsers. After vetting my code through JsHint and other tools, I checked on IE console. And this seems to be the only problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been breaking my head on thsi for a long time.
[image: Error console snapshot]

[image: Call Stack Snapshot]

Comment: I pasted the code shown into IE and it didn't give any errors. Have you tried (temporarily) removing that line to see what happens?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the error. And the line 169 that it shows is the one I have mentioned as  in my js file.

Comment: Which version of IE, they're all very different.

Comment: Note that the line number IE gives the errors for are *not* the same as it will appear in your code. If you click the blue link on the right of the error in the console it'll take you to the offending line

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan clicking on the blue link says 'source code is not available for this location'. I am running this on my local machine. Also, in the js.js file that the error shows, line 169 is the one i have posted

Comment: Silly thought: have you tried to remove the blank space before `:` in the line of the error?  It shouldn't be an issue, but it's IE, you know...

Comment: @GermanLatorre it actually had no space and still was the same case. So i tried adding  the space

Comment: @GermanLatorre - No version of IE would be bothered by a space like that.

Comment: Okay, I said it was a silly thought, :-D

Comment: Should I post the whole JS script ? But it is a long one !

Comment: A screenshot of the callstack in from the debugger could be of any help

Comment: To the OP: Note that you originally asked about an **un**expected colon, but the error messages in the screenshot say "expected :", i.e., the opposite problem.

Comment: @GermanLatorre have posted the callstack snapshot

Comment: No luck, it provides no interesting info like that... And attaching screenshots of each call stack step would be a pain... Anyway, it seems to be an error while loading JS via Ajax.  Seeing full contents of both `index.php` and `js.js` (both files seem to trigger the error) could help.

Comment: But wouldn't posting them here make it too long ? And I would be voted or closed out of this question in a jiffy  :-D Any ideas ?